# Tensorflow feature engineering for Boolean types

Tags: python, tensorflow

My dataset (CSV format) contains a boolean type (0 or 1)
When I'm defining my features in Tensorflow I have been defining float64 as `tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column`.

```
salesPercentile                  333919 non-null float64
```

Using `real_valued_column`:

```
sales_percentile = tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column('sales_percentile')
```

What option do I have for boolean types?

```
nationBestSeller         333919 non-null bool
localBestSeller          333919 non-null bool
```

Comment: You probably won't find boolean layer types as they're not differentiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

real_valued_column should handle the bool too. since for the network it's a float value (one or zero)